# Reduce anchor hit area in html

Tags: html, css

On my current website, I have a banner-image, where I have reduced the bottom-margin, so that the content below is moved a bit further up on the page. The banner also has an anchor-tag on it, to link to the "home"-page.

However, the hit area of the anchor, is not reduced accordingly. Since negative padding is not valid, and my googling turned up nothing, I ask here for advice.

Is there a way to reduce the hit area of the anchor tag?

[image]

Relevant Html:

```
  <a class="site-title" href="/">
    <img class="logo" src="logo.svg" alt="Logo">
  </a>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.logo {
  margin-bottom: -26px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem? this is the image size

Comment: yes, this is the image-size. However, hitting the Buttons below (Home, Portfolio, About) doesn't work. At least there should be some separation between the hit areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way this could be done is to have the image separated from the link and just have the link/click area as an overlay on top of the image so you can control the image positioning & dimensions independently of the clickable area. For example...

HTML:

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="logo.svg">
  <a href="/"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image{ position: relative; margin-bottom: -26px; }
.image a{ position: absolute; display: block; width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 26px); }
```

Alternatively, you can play with z-indexing, but I think this approach might be the cleanest since the logo does overlap with the bar in the design/screenshots.

Comment: This works great, except that the nav-bar is partly unclickable. Probably due to z-indexing. I tried to fix it with various z-indexes, but no luck.

Comment: You can try adding `pointer-events: none` as a css attribute to the image

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Saw specific issue concerning the links over image. Edited accordingly. For the links, add `position:relative` and `z-index:1` or higher. Instead of using negative margin, use the `bottom` property to move the links up. I added the `title` attribute to demonstrate that all links are exposed, just hover over the links and you'll notice the different titles.

---

Ditch that void element (ie `<img>`) and then make `<a>`nchor `inline-block` with a `background-image`

**SNIPPET**

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
}

.logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://imgh.us/gir_zim.gif)no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header class='site-title'>
  <a class="logo" href="#/" title='logo'></a>
  <nav><a href='#/' title='link1'>LINK1</a>&nbsp;<a href='#/' title='lin2k'>LINK2</a></nav>
</header>
```